# Why this.$el gives undefined error but $(this.el) works inside render function in Backbone view?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-views

I am quite new to backbone.js with little experience in javaScript. I was trying various backbone tutorial found here and there. e.g. from this tutorial I was trying to learn

[backbone-baby-steps](http://codebyexample.info/2012/03/06/backbone-baby-steps/#more-35)

In most of the tutorials like above one, they use following code inside `Backbone.View.extend` to set the model in html template and then render it,

```
render: function() {
    var tmpl = _.template(this.template);
    this.$el.html(tmpl(this.model.toJSON()));
    return this;
    }
```

but when I run the code in chrome debugger it says this `this.$el` is undefined. I searched a lot but didn't get the solution, then I modified the code by own and it worked,

```
$(this.el).html(tmpl(this.model.toJSON()));
```

I'm using `cdnjs` hosted libraries for backbone, underscore and jquery.

I want to know why every backbone tutorial on internet is using `this.$el` version but it doesn't work for me?

And also, when I use the the library(backbone, underscore etc.) files provided by the tutorials instead of hosted one, chrome debugger gives various errors in libraries, why?

Comment: Wats the version of `backbone` you're using ?

Comment: http://ajax.cdnjs.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/0.3.3/backbone-min.js

Comment: try upgrading to `0.9.0` or newer one, `this.$el` property - `a cached jQuery (or Zepto) reference to the view's element` was added in that version. You can refer to the change log of 0.9.0 in [docs](http://backbonejs.org/).

Comment: Thanks... I was using very old version. Now it's working with `this.$el`

Comment: I've posted an answer, so that we can reduce unanswered questions by one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As per the change log specified in the [docs](http://backbonejs.org/), `$el` property - `a cached jQuery (or Zepto) reference to the view's element` was added in version `0.9.0`. Try upgrading the version of `backbone` you're using to `0.9.0` or above. It should work after that.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define in your View like below

```
var ElementView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $("#picker")
}
```